# Is there a way to make multiple horizontal boxplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a matplotlib figure that will have multiple horizontal boxplots stacked on one another. The documentation shows both how to make a single horizontal boxplot and how to make multiple vertically oriented plots [in this section.](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot)

I tried using subplots as in the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

totfigs = 5

plt.figure()
plt.hold = True

for i in np.arange(totfigs):    
    x = np.random.random(50)
    plt.subplot('{0}{1}{2}'.format(totfigs,1,i+1))
    plt.boxplot(x,vert=0)
plt.show()
```

My output results in just a single horizontal boxplot though.

Any suggestions anyone?

**Edit**: Thanks to @joaquin, I fixed the `plt.subplot` call line. Now the subplot version works, but still would like the boxplots all in one figure...

Comment: this code produces an exception: `IndexError: list index out of range` in the plt.subplot line

Comment: thanks @joaquin - you are right. I fixed it. Now I can make the subplot option work fine. It would still be nice to put the plots on a single figure without subplots though....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just need to pass boxplot a list (or a 2d array) containing each array you want to plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

totfigs = 5

plt.figure()
plt.hold = True
boxes=[]
for i in np.arange(totfigs):    
    x = np.random.random(50)
    boxes.append(x)

plt.boxplot(boxes,vert=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: exactly! I didn't realize I could make them a list first. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
plt.subplot('{0}{1}{2}'.format(totfigs, 1, i+1)    # n rows, 1 column
```

or

```
plt.subplot('{0}{1}{2}'.format(1, totfigs, i+1))    # 1 row, n columns
```

from the docstring:

> subplot(*args, **kwargs)
>
> Create a subplot command, creating axes with::
>
> subplot(numRows, numCols, plotNum)
>
> where *plotNum* = 1 is the first plot number and increasing *plotNums*
>   fill rows first.  max(*plotNum*) == *numRows* * *numCols*

if you want them all together, shift them conveniently. As an example with a constant shift:

```
for i in np.arange(totfigs):    
    x = np.random.random(50)
    plt.boxplot(x+(i*2),vert=0)
```

Comment: yep - I saw that was my error. Still doesn't address the other desire to avoid using subplots though...

Comment: @mishaF the last alternative **does not** use subplots at all

Comment: right, but these plots are arranged horizontally. I was hoping for a group of horizontally oriented boxplots stacked vertically on top of each other. In other words, I need a vertical rather than horizontal shift.

Comment: Making vert=1 changes their orientation. the picture Stephen posted above is what I meant. Sorry I wasn't probably being very clear.