# How can I print two boxplots on the same axis in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, axes

I'm using matplotlib to graph two boxplots. I am able to get them printed as subplots on the same figure, but I am having trouble getting them side by side on the same set of axes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665771/is-there-a-way-to-make-multiple-horizontal-boxplots-in-matplotlib)

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? What kind of trouble? You cannot display 2 boxes on the same axis at all? Or you cannot make them side by side, i.e. they overlap? It would be best if you provided the code of what you did, a minimal example of what you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code which finally worked:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
axes[0].boxplot(mads_dp52)
axes[1].boxplot(mads_dp53)
plt.show()
```